# I cannot import module

Tags: javascript

Pls I need assistance, am practicing on importing module but my code is not working. I have tried all I could to know where the problem is from but no way.

I keep getting this error:

script2.js:1

```
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at script2.js:1:1)
```

there is the snippet

```
 import { addToCart } from './minScript.js';
    
 addToCart('bread', 5);
```

// Below is from the minScript.js. NB both are in the same directory

```
export const addToCart = function (product, quantity) {
  cart.push({ product, quantity });
  console.log(`${product}, ${quantity} was added to  cart`);
};
```

pls I really need help am just a beginner

Comment: `import './script3.js';` — Import *what*? You got the syntax for [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) wrong. Check the manual for it.

Comment: Is the module in the same directory as your file importing it?

Comment: You should provide more in your `minScript.js` file to let us know how you exported your module. You may check out [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) and [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) docs.

Comment: The message says that the error is _the very first character_ of the file... How are you running this code?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.js`, like:

```
import { addToCart } from './minScript';
```

Try your best,